# Apollo server v2 implementation with Nextjs

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js, backend, apollo

I'm trying to use apollo server in my next js routes, and I saw a lot of videos were people use the library 'apollo-server-micro', to create a '/api/graphql' handler. I wanted to know how can I reproduce the same functionality using apollo server v2 `apollo-server`

**My main goal is to create a handler for my /api/graphql route in my Nextjs App**

That's how it's done with apollo server micro (example)

```js
  
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-micro'

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    users: [User!]!
  }
  type User {
    name: String
  }
`

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users(parent, args, context) {
      return [{ name: 'Nextjs' }]
    },
  },
}

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}

export default apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' }) // that's the main thing I wanted to do in my server.
```